# Direct Write in Function Behaving As Pass By Value

Tags: c++, function, lifetime

I have been chasing this problem down for a week now but I don't know why it's happening so am unable to fix it. I am using a function to write directly to variables that have been declared outside of that function (i.e. not passed as arguments to the function in any way) , the value does not persist when the function ends.

Depending on where if and where I assign a value to num, I have seen three things:

1. The lifetime of the last assigned value of num doesn't survive the exit of MyFunc().
2. The lifetime of the last assigned value of num survives while within the function that is calling MyFunc(), which is TestFunc() in this example. This is how the MyFunc() is intended to work in normal operation: num is initialized once by the constructor and never have it's value set by MyFunc(). MyFunc() only ever increment num when it is run, always picking up num from where it left off each time it is called.
3. In cases where MyFunc() never sets the value of num, and only ever increments it, the value of num persists globally as long as MyFunc() is not called again. As soon as MyFunc() is called again, it uses the initialized value of num rather than working from where it left off.

This occurs  in both C and C++ versions of the code.

a. In the C++ version (shown here), I am using class member functions to write to class member variables.

b. In the C version (not shown), instead of a class with member variables and functions, I have standalone functions that accept a pointer to the structure type as an argument, and dereferences the structure to access it's member variables.

This is running on an STM32F303 K8 (ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller) using Rowley Crossworks. I need to use <> to tag some pseudo code to tell you what's going on since this isn't in the actual system and it's a bit more involved to read stuff out.

I boiled down the code as much as I could but left in some things that might seem extraneous. These things are there because they seem to matter and are representative of what is there so they might seem like useless placeholders. (For example, `num = 1;` being before or after the `if(true)` statement changes the results)

In this test code, the member function writes to the member variable a few times and reads it out at various times. Please ignore little syntax errors if there are any since this is a stripped, generalized version of the code and the actual code I am working with compiles and runs.

## Header file

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    unsigned num;

    void MyFunc();
    MyClass(unsigned FirstNum);
};

extern MyClass MyObject;
```

## C++ file

```
MyClass MyObject(0);

MyClass::MyClass(unsigned FirstNum)
{
  num = FirstNum;
}

void MyClass::MyFunc()
{
  //num = 1; //uncomment this and only this for SCENARIO A
  if(true)
  {
    //num = 1; //uncomment this and only this for SCENARIO B

              //comment both for SCENARIO C

    for(unsigned n = 0; n < 3;)
    {
      n++;
      num++;
      <PRINT NUM TO TERMINAL>
    }
  }
}

void TestMyFunc
{
  <some setup code to test conditions to test MyFunc() is here>
  MyObject::MyFunc();

  //NOTE: that if I was to run <prinout MyObject::num> directly right here, I can get different results than if if I encapsulate the command in dummy function before I run it. The two values I can get are either the last assigned value of num or the value that num was initialized to before MyFunc was called.
}
```

## TOP LEVEL C++ file

```
int main()
{
  CallingFunc();
  <PRINT MYNUM TO TERMINAL>

  CallingFunc(); //this second call is only relevant for Scenario C and is to demonstrate how Num always starts off at the value initialized by the constructor whenever it is called if no explicit assignment is made at the start of in MyFunc()
  <PRINT MYNUM TO TERMINAL> 
}
```

## Output

```
SCENARIO A: 2 3 4 4   2 3 4 4     --last assignment is maintained when MyFunc() exits. 
SCENARIO B: 2 3 4 0   2 3 4 0  --MyNum reverts to the value initialized by the its constructor when MyFunc() exits. This is also the output if I remove the if(true) conditional check.
SCENARIO C: 1 2 3 3   1 2 3 3  --MyNum is initialized by the constructor and is only incremented in MyFunc(). Value maintained after MyFunc() exits, but not, but is always reset to initialized value every time another call is made, despite having no "num =" in MyFunc().
Expected Results for Scenario A: AS EXPECTED
Expected Results for Scenario B: 2 3 4 4  2 3 4 4
Expected Results for Scenario C: 1 2 3 3  4 5 6 6
```

Also, note that something similar was happening even in the C version of the code where class members variables and functions were replaced by struct member variables and functions external to the struct. The struct as a whole was passed via pointer to the function.

Does anyone have any idea why it seems like assigning member variables directly, or struct members via pointers almost makes them seem like there is a copy-by value going on?

Comment: It's unclear where the variable `MyNum` is declared. Also, the line `// MyNum = 7;` is not uncommented in any "scenario" and can be removed from the example--or you did not mention why it is there. What if you carefully make *compilable* examples with two different .cpp versions. for the scenarios A and B? It would be easier to follow. Also, `TX_Buffer` and the `extern` declaration in the .h do not seem to be relevant, unless they are--but then please explain why.

Comment: The significance of `if (true)` is also dubious.

Comment: I made a few corrections while you were responding. Statement such as `extern` and `If(true)` are there for representative reasons since I couldn't rule them out. In particular, the `if(true)` is there to let you know there is something there. In reality it's checking a flag that has been manually set. It seems to be relevant as described in Scenario A vs B

Comment: `MyFunc::MyFunc` is not a part of the class `MyClass`, but another (irrtatingly similarly named) unrelated function, and it is never called.

Comment: Think where the printed `3` comes from in scenario A, when num is never assigned 3. Magic? I do not think, honestly, that output matches the example you are giving.

Comment: I made some corrections and modifications. Thanks for your patience. It's been really hard for me to put into words what I'm seeing.

Comment: I stripped down the code onto an online compliler and got different behaviour that made a bit more sense in that Scenario B now outputs the same thing as Scenario A. Maybe it's something to do with the hardware I'm working or the optimizer though I don't know what that would be.

The server crashed before I managed to narrow down why the last assignment in the previous function call gets reset and is not used in the next function call for Scenario C so will have to try again tommorrow.

Comment: I found the root of the issue (doesn't seem to explain why some of the more detailed strange behaviour is happening but they go away when I fix the root). I was encapsulating test functions to much and forgot some initialization code existed and it was getting run multiple times.

Comment: So the problem was not a coding issue at all. Could someone please close this question for me? I don't have enough rep to do it.